# Unable to resolve the request yii

Tags: php, yii

I am new in Yii and sorry to say that anyone help me please that why the controller employeController.php not called , I check and set many files permission etc ,

Here is my url http://dxb.softmatics.com:81/erp/index.php/employe/index

Controller :    /*.........for on board controller....*/

```
class employeController extends Controller{

    /**
     * Declares class-based actions.
     */
    public function actions()
    {

        return array(
            'page'=>array(
                'class'=>'CViewAction',
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
    * for index page 
    */
    public function actionIndex()
        {
            echo 'in index';
            exit;
        }
}//...end of class
```

If any thing else I will show you my code like config etc

Comment: What error are u getting ??

Comment: Usually the controller is called like: `your_application/index.php?r=Employer/index`

Comment: In your example: http://dxb.softmatics.com:81/erp/index.php?r=employe/index

Comment: Error 404
Unable to resolve the request "employe/index"  , and i even try url like this dxb.softmatics.com:81/erp/index.php?r=Employer/index , by setting config , main.php

Comment: No Employer but Employe (without R) that is the name of your controller `employeController`

Comment: Just click on my link..... it's working buddy...

Comment: **Note**: Your controller filename is `EmployeeController`, while class name is `employeeController`, always use same letter case to avoid problems, prefably first letter should be uppercase in class name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the controller as:

```
index.php?r=ControllerName/ActionName
```

In your case:

[`dxb.softmatics.com:81/erp/index.php?r=employe/index`](http://dxb.softmatics.com:81/erp/index.php?r=employe/index)

Also, you can add modules, such as:

```
index.php?r=ModuleName/ControllerName/ActionName
```

Reference: [Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller)

Comment: Hi, please check i set the URL manager now my url is  http://dxb.softmatics.com:81/erp/index.php?r=employe/index but still getting the same error :(

Comment: Do you have the method `actionIndex` on your `employeController`? It was working before.

Comment: Yes i have  , You can view my employeController.php class code above ,

Answer (score 0):

This URL is working: `dxb.softmatics.com:81/erp/index.php?r=employe/index`

but if you don't see your echo in `index` - the problem is: in the layout you should to set name of default controller - not `Site`, but `Employe` (you can set proper name for each layout)

or set in `config.php` default controller as `employe` if you have one.

Comment: Thanks to all of you , I got the error , the file is on Linux server and the issue was spell mistake (lower and uppercase)  , I am very thankful to all of you to help me alot , Thanks...:)

Comment: Now my controller file name is EmployeController.php , and class EmployeController is this , and url will be like /employe/index, Thanks to all of you ...:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is case of controller name and its file. It should be `EmployeController` and `EmployeController.php`. Yii will capitalize controller name defined in route and will look for controller at `controllers/EmployeController.php`. For case sensitive filesystems (like in Linux) file will not be found, so Yii will assume that controller does not exist and will return 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where the controller/action was working fine on local (MAC OS X) but not on my server (Linux).

The issue was that the **PHP opcache** on the server needed to be flushed.

Hope this helps someone struggling with a similar issue!